# WordPress jQuery fires only after refresh

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to load my CSS async so what I have done is the following on all css styles I load them as `media = none` and once the page is loaded I use jQuery to change attr value to `media = all`.

Issue that I keep getting and I can't seem to solve is that, this only works after I refresh the page. On first load all I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

Also when I navigate to the next page I need to refresh again for the jQuery to fire.

I am working in word press so this is what I am doing:

**functions.php**

```
function wpic_theme_js(){
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate');
  wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js', array(), '', false);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('app_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpic_theme_js');
```

in my **jQuery script** I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery('link[media="none"]').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('media', 'all');
    });
```

also as you can tell I have `deregistered` jquery-migrate for the same reason I am getting `jQuery is not defined` error.

If anyone has a solution for this I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

PS>
I am making a little progress here, I notice that jQuery is not fully loaded. Looks like jQuery library and my app.js file are loading at almost exact same time. So when it fires jQuery is not defined yet..

URL: http://iamcavic.com/

I got it to work but I have a flicker now :(

Comment: Are you loading Jquery before the call??

Comment: @JotaGe you can see in his code that he is...

Comment: Make sure your script should be written/ included after jquery

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is clearly the wrong approach. All jQuery actions within WordPress need to be transfered and triggered through admin-ajax.php.

It is a bit misleading by the name, but this file is responsible to do ajax request to the backend/theme/.

One google search:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I don't follow why would you link to this article since I am not using AJAX anywhere in my project? Also my function is a core function of the website not just admin area. Please clarify if I am misunderstanding your answer. Thank you

Comment: Since you are doing an asynchronous action, it will trigger an internal WordPress filter / restriction. WordPress will not allow you to trigger an ajax request outside the method that I gave you. In other words: you have to do ajax requests this way, no way around - at least not that I know of.

Comment: @user2521387 Questioner not ask for ajax call he just run a simple jQuery

Comment: How else would you do an asynch loading of css? The way he is doing it is fake loading..

Comment: Thanks for help but my problem is not CSS my problem is jQuery related. Files are loaded with no problem I have issue with jQuery, which once I refresh the page goes away. To me it feels like jQuery is not fully loaded before my function executes, so jQuery is still loading and my function fires which results in jQuery error.

Comment: Only thing that I can think of by looking at your code is that your new jQuery should be in the footer, but it's not. Set last param to true to move it to the footer and test it.

Comment: I just tried that and same issue, however now it loads in the footer instead but no difference.